# Click event is fired more than once in Internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have an hyperlink as:

```
<a href="#" class="search">Search</a>
```

On clicking the `hyperlink` I will get pop-up and I will perform advance search with **Advance Search** button in pop-up dialog with the **`jqgrid`**.

After clicking **Advance Search**  button, It will call controller and returns grid.

My `button's` code is:

```
<a id="searchResults" class="btn btn-primary">Advance Search</a>
```

My `jquery` is:

```
 $('.search').on('click', function () {
      search();
  });


function search() {
    $('#searchResults').unbind('click').on('click', function () {
        searchClick();
     });
}
```

When I am using it in **Google chrome**, it works fine.

But, when I'm using it in **Internet explorer(Version:9)**, then **`$('.search').on('click',function(){..});`** is **called more than once** and my `controller` throws "**Session timed out**" exception. Finally, I will get redirected to the **login page**.

Actually, it is fetching the grid results on clicking **Advance Search** on first click event. But, if it calls for second time, then the controller `throws` Exception.

But I don't know why it is calling the event `$('.search').on('click',function(){..});` for the second,third,... times in **Internet Explorer**.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to add e.stoppropagation();

Comment: Would you please try to replace "a" with "span" with sample class?

Comment: Not working with span..

Comment: Yes you are right! Instead of e.stopPropagation() I used e.preventDefault()

Comment: Hi @Vikash, If my answer helpful to you, please rate me below I have comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with

```
  e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace .unbind("click") with .off("click") or .one("click")**

```
function search() {
    $('#searchResults').off('click').on('click', function () {
        searchClick();
     });
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code 
you are attaching click event on a.search and you want a#searchResults to trigger?

if it is so then 
$('#searchResults').trigger('click');
will be sufficient.

Comment: I dont want to trigger the click event, But just I want to bind the event

Answer (score 0):

Instead of e.stopPropagation(), I used e.preventDefault() and works fine. Thanks @Kushal Vora

I got solution and code is:

```
 $('.search').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     search();
 });
```